# Sorting alphabetically a-z and z-a by using dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> I working on a react app where I am displaying movies data. I want to
>   sort data based on Title from a-z and z-a by selecting from dropdown.
>   Check the below code. Unable to sort correctly with this approach. As I see 
>   there is problem in onSorting

App.js -

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      sort_term: '', movies: data.movies
    }
    this.onSorting = this.onSorting.bind(this);
  }
  onSorting(e) {
    let term = e.target.value;
    const sortedList = this.state.movies.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a[term] > b[term]) return 1;
      if (b[term] > a[term]) return -1;
      return 0;
    });
    this.setState({ sort_term: term });
    this.setState({ movies: sortedList });
  }


  render() {
    const { movies } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header sort_term={this.state.sort_term}
          onSorting={this.onSorting} />

        {movies.length === 0 ?
          <h1>Loading Movies</h1> :
          <Table movies={this.state.movies} />}

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

> Header.js - here is the dropdown box with two options

```
class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        const { sort_term, onSorting } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="nav">
                <ul className="navLeft">
                    <li >
                        <form >
                            <select value={sort_term}
                                onChange={onSorting}
                                className="searchBar">
                                <option value="Title"> Sort (A - Z)</option>
                                <option value="Title"> Sort (Z - A) </option>
                            </select>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Table.js -

```
class Table extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
    }

    render() {
        const list = this.props.movies.map((movie) => (
            <tr key={movie.Title}>
                <td>{movie.Title}</td>
                <td>{movie.Director}</td>
            </tr>
        )
        );

        return (
            <div className="table">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Director</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {list}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: `sort` doesn't return a new array, it does an in place modification of the array its called on. this is why sometimes you see `arr.slice().sort(fn)`

Comment: ya same array only should be sorted

Comment: well when you do `sorted = arr.sort(fn)` it won't work because you're not creating a new state. you're just copying the reference to the array, react won't know how to resort it

Comment: @azium, it returns the sorted array for me. Is it weird?

Comment: @devserkan it "returns" the **same** array. both `arr.sort()` and `arr = arr.sort()` are equivalent

Comment: Ok, same array but a sorted one right? I'm asking this only learning purposes. Since it actually works to set a state as seen in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your code is working but since you sort `A-Z` you don't see the difference probably. Just change the sort function's related part like that:

```
if (a[term] > b[term]) return -1;
if (b[term] > a[term]) return 1;
```

Edit: If you have a non-sorted array your code should work. I tried it with a sorted list this is why I told you to change the order.

```js
const movies = [
  { Title: "poo", Director: "poo" },
  { Title: "foo", Director: "bar" },
  { Title: "zoo", Director: "moo" },
]

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      sort_term: '', movies,
    }
    this.onSorting = this.onSorting.bind(this);
  }

  
  onSorting(e) {
    let term = e.target.value;
    const sortedList = [...this.state.movies].sort((a, b) => {
      return a[term].localeCompare(b[term]);
    });
    this.setState({ sort_term: term });
    this.setState({ movies: sortedList });
  }


  render() {
    const { movies } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header sort_term={this.state.sort_term}
          onSorting={this.onSorting} />

        {movies.length === 0 ?
          <h1>Loading Movies</h1> :
          <Table movies={this.state.movies} />}

      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { sort_term, onSorting } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="nav">
        <ul className="navLeft">
          <li >
            <form >
              <select value={sort_term}
                onChange={onSorting}
                className="searchBar">
                <option value="Title"> Sort (A - Z)</option>
                <option value="Title"> Sort (Z - A) </option>
              </select>
            </form>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {}
  }

  render() {
    const list = this.props.movies.map((movie) => (
      <tr key={movie.Title}>
        <td>{movie.Title}</td>
        <td>{movie.Director}</td>
      </tr>
    )
    );

    return (
      <div className="table">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Director</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {list}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

But, you don't have a sort direction logic in your code. You are using the same sort function and it does a one-way sort right now.

Also, do not use the state directly like that since you are mutating it. Use `concat` or something like that:

```
const sortedList = [...this.state.movies].sort((a, b) => {
      if (a[term] > b[term]) return -1;
      if (b[term] > a[term]) return 1;
      return 0;
});
```

Even better, you can use `localCompare` to make the sort more reliable. Thanks to @msbit for the comment and pointing out that.

```
const sortedList = [...this.state.movies].sort((a, b) => {
      return a[term].localeCompare(b[term]);
});
```

Comment: You could also consider using `localeCompare` to make the sorting more reliable: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Comment: Thank you @msbit. I will definitely consider in the future. Also, I will update my answer later.

Comment: This code will sort in descending. As I have dropdown option as Ascending and Descending , I need to sort both ways